# Removing the first x lines from a string

Tags: php

```
function remove_lines($str, $lines = 2) { //Here x is 2
    return implode("\n", array_slice(explode("\n", $str), $lines));
}
```

Suppose I have data like

```
5
4
7
2
5
```

the function removes the first 2 lines and displays

```
7 2 5
```

But I need

```
7
2
5
```

Comment: Is it alwaysarray or string some time?

Comment: Do you look at the browser output?

Comment: See the link [link]http://msdasaradh.16mb.com/trademate/test.php for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you viewing it through the browser? Try using the break tag instead of a newline character.

```
implode("<br/>", array_slice(explode("\n", $str), $lines));
```